# trigger every key press in android in background

Tags: android, keyboard

i am developing android service and I want to know is there anyway that can let me know what is the user typing every key clicked whatever keyboard he is using
for example if the user clicked the letter 'k' from samsung keyboard, i want my service to know that, I could manage this if the user used my custom keyboard, but I want to know even if he is using his default keyboard. and thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible. But If it was allowed won't it be a security issue?

Comment: well, its just POC it will not be uploaded on google play! anyhow, google reject these apps ..

Comment: and there is alot of keylogger apps in he internet, not in google play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know is there anyway that can let me know what is the user typing every key clicked whatever keyboard he is using

**NO, there is no way and it's completely illegal.**

However Android let you the opportunity the create a custom keyboard using `InputMethodService`. Once you have created soft custom keyboard and the user have enabled it then you can track every key of user with the callback method `onKey()` 
Also, let me remind you that this is only for the good intentions like word-suggestions and predictions