# Xamarin Android read bluetooth barcode scanner

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to read the output of a HID Bluetooth barcode scanner in Xamarin Android in the background? I do not want to use an inputbox.

I would like to use this one:
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0753S29QW?ref_=cm_sw_r_cp_ud_dp_9YHX0TY2470E4641VC85

Comment: See the complete manual https://www.inateckoffice.com/pages/bcst-70-barcode-scanner-support-page. You would need to connect to your machine Bluetooth interface and then read from blue tooth interface.  So you first have to setup the blue tooth and then send/read messages from scanner.

Comment: Is HID and background inconsistent? Usually, HID will be used in the foreground. If Android has a keyboard hook mechanism with a background process, it will be possible. Perhaps these articles will be helpful. [trigger every key press in android in background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48484024/9014308), [pqpo/InputMethodHolder](https://github.com/pqpo/InputMethodHolder), [Get Keyboard key press in Background Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53084593/9014308), [Create a log of all keyboard key pressed during a day in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22629145/9014308)